# Rstudio autocomplete variables

Tags: r, rstudio

I am new to both R and Rstudio. I like the autocompletion of functions, models and data.frames. My question concerns autocompletion of variables.

So lets say I load the well known iris data.

I can start typing "ir", click click tab and get the rest of the dataset to autocomplete.

I also know can get the names of the variables by various means such as `names(iris)`. Which I can copy and paste.

Now, how can I do a good autocomplete with variables? I would like to be able to type "pet" and tab and it gives me the different possible variables options to autocomplete (like it does for functions).

Is something like that possible?

The only workaround I can see is type out the full `dataset$variable` name such as `iris$` then tab, when then allows me to select `iris$petalwitdth`. But that it more typing and makes for some ugly code. I just want "petalwidth" to autocomplete.

Options? Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `iris$P` <kbd>tab</kbd> is preferable, but if you must, you can attach the dataset to the search path

```
attach(iris)
```

Then, `P` <kbd>tab</kbd> will auto complete

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I had seen "attach", but not sure what it did.

Comment: Well, it's evil, so use it with caution.