# Is autocompletion possible for udf? As in tidyverse: user types in first letters and selection menu appears

Tags: r, variables, selection

See this example where dplyr does autocompletion:

[image: typeahead]

I just typed `my_` and a select menu appears including objects beginging with `my_` inside the global environment *and* inside of `df. On the other hand, see what happens if I type same first letters inside my own function` my_fun`:

[image: typeahead does not work]

As you can see, here only the `my_fun` from the global environment appears in the list but the two variable names from `df` are missing! Can we do the autocompletion list as in the first screenshot for a user defined function?

---

**Code**. But keep in mind that this selection menu does not appear if you copy paste the first letters `my_` - you have to actually type in `my_` and then the menu appears.

```
df <- data.frame(my_var1= 1:5, my_var2= 6:10)
my_fun <- function(data, var){mean(data[ , var])}
df %>% mutate(my_)
my_fun(data= df, var= my_)
```

**Edit**: I want it to be "live", so the menu selection appears right after the first letters, i.e. user does not need to run code.

**What I got so far**: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280981/rstudio-autocomplete-variables) we see that we can use `attach` for autocompletion. So if we use `attach(df)` first, the variable names of `df` appear in the list. But for this user must `run` code in advance, i.e. it is not "live" as in first screenshot.

Comment: I believe the behavior you are looking for is usually referred to as typeahead/autocomplete and it usually a feature of the IDE. From the screenshot it looks like you are using Rstudio. Have you tried writing a package as you suggested? This should normally work out of the box. If not share what you have tried.

Comment: can you rephrase the question then? It seems a bit vague, at least to me. Are you trying to build something like esquisse? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/esquisse/vignettes/get-started.html

Comment: I see but at least I fail to understand how what you are asking for is any different from Rstudio's default behavior. I.e. the feature you are asking for should already be there "out of the box". In any case, I would suggest to look at the rstudioapi package if you are curious about manipulating the behavior of the ide. https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241610/discussion-between-benjamin-schwetz-and-stats-and-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note how you are using the magrittr pipe with `mutate` but not with `my_fun`. You will need to use the pipe operator to trigger data-variables to appear in the autocomplete menu:

### No data-variables in autocomplete:

[image]

### data-variables in autocomplete

[image]